# How to open an image in new tab with magnifier

Tags: jquery, html, image, href

I'm new to Jquery. I have an image that needs to be opened in another tab with a magnifier. 
I did the following using `featherlight.js`.This opens in a new tab but I don't know to how to add a magnifier to this image.

```
<a href="images/course_layout.jpg" data-featherlight="image"><img src="images/course_layout.jpg" /></a>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this.
http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/magnifying-glass-for-images-using-jquery-and-css3

Hope it can help you.